# Battery: energy-full-design much lesser than energy-full?

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

I replaced the battery of my laptop. The battery seems to work, but the max charging value is higher than the max charging value by design:

```
upower -i "$(upower -e | grep -P "_BAT")"

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               xxx
  model:                DELL xxx
  serial:               xxx
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun 23 Aug 2020 02:08:02 PM CEST (97 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              59.4776 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         67.9972 Wh
    energy-full-design:  50.9922 Wh
    energy-rate:         8.4056 W
    voltage:             7.934 V
    time to empty:       7.1 hours
    percentage:          87%
    capacity:            35.7702%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
```

Is this normal? Actually, the new battery is physically bigger than the old battery, but it seems to me strange that the nominal value is so low.

The laptop is a Dell Latitude 5480; I use Lubuntu 18.04.5. The new battery is compatible, not original; 7.6V, 68Wh. The old one is nominally a 11.4V, 51Wh.

Comment: OS? Version? What kind of replacement battery did you use? Same as your original? What are the part numbers? Original or rebuild? How exactly did you get those settings?